# -1 < 4 return NO? It's so strange

Tags: objective-c, arrays

```
int counter=-1;
NSArray *pointArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"1",@"2", nil];
NSString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter<pointArray.count-1];
```

Believe it or not the result is 0 !!!
Try and who can tell me why???

Comment: `NSString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter<(int)pointArray.count-1];`it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the following code reproduces this issue:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSUInteger uns = 4;
    int sig = -1;
    BOOL cmp = (sig < uns);
    NSLog(@"(%d<%zu)=%d", sig, uns, cmp);
}
```

The output of this is

```
 (-1<4)=0
```

---

As has been pointed out, the trouble is that you are comparing an `int` to an `NSUInteger`.  But recall that, on 64-bit systems, `NSUInteger` is a [`typedef` of `unsigned long`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html).

The behavior we're seeing is a result of [usual arithmetic conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t4w2bkb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> 1. If either operand is of type long double, the other operand is converted to type long double.
> 2. If the above condition is not met and either operand is of type double, the other operand is converted to type double.
> 3. If the above two conditions are not met and either operand is of type float, the other operand is converted to type float.
> 4. If the above three conditions are not met (none of the operands are of floating types), then integral conversions are performed on the operands as follows:
>
>    - If either operand is of type unsigned long, the other operand is converted to type unsigned long.
>    - If the above condition is not met and either operand is of type long and the other of type unsigned int, both operands are converted to type unsigned long.
>    - If the above two conditions are not met, and either operand is of type long, the other operand is converted to type long.
>    - If the above three conditions are not met, and either operand is of type unsigned int, the other operand is converted to type unsigned int.
>    - If none of the above conditions are met, both operands are converted to type int.

Since neither of the operands are of floating point type, we arrive at `4.`.  Since the second operand (`pointArray.count-1`) is of type `NSUInteger`, that is of type `unsigned long`, the other operand (`counter`) is converted to type `unsigned long`, taking on the value of `18446744073709551615` which is indeed greater than `4`.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing a signed number (-1) to an unsigned number (pointArray.count - 1).

Comment: Except normally that would cause the unsigned to be promoted to signed, IIRC.

Comment: One would think. But assigning `pointArray.count - 1` to an `int`, and then comparing `counter` to the `int`, does indeed do the right thing.